# React Native Grid of Buttons

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm new to react-native, and I'm trying to make a grid of buttons where I can change the number of buttons per row and the overall number of buttons. Making the grid itself is not a problem but changing the number of items per row is harder. Could anyone give me some advice on what I should use to achieve this goal? I'm using flex-box and ListView right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you to use  ListView, try to create a new component instead which represent each row on the grid and also create a componen which represents each button on the ro. Then you can easily create as many button as you want on each row and also you will be able to modify their styles.

You can still use flexbox order the elements at the center.